# Should multiple cities in publisher names, like “Amsterdam–New York”, use en-dash or hyphen?

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, typography

Often, publishers list multiple cities in their address, like “Amsterdam–New York–London”; these appear very frequently in bibliographies.  **Should these be typeset with an en-dash, or a hyphen, or is this style-dependent?**

I can’t find any style guides or typography guides mentioning this explicitly, and general rules for dash use seem to imply that en-dashes would be appropriate — it seems analogous to e.g. concatenating names of authors in a multi-author theorem.

On the other hand, most published papers seem to use hyphens, and major bibdata repositories (e.g. MathSciNet, DBLP) provide bibdata using hyphens for this.  But then again, you also find numerical page ranges given with hyphens in many such places, which is definitely not correct — so “common practice” (even in professional publishing) sometimes just reflects common errors, rather than established best practices.

Are there any authoritative guidelines on this point?

Comment: I would use neither an endash nor a hyphen. Instead, I would wite `Amsterdam, New York, and London`. For sure, it can't be *wrong* to use commas.

Comment: I've seen with separating commas, or just an interword space.

Comment: I agree with Mico _and_ Bernard. Either commas or spaces! But not the final comma in British English: `Amsterdam, New York and London` or `Amsterdam New York London`. If you insist using dashes, `en-dashes` with spaces on both sides, never hyphens.

Comment: Many style guides [citation needed] want only the first city listed. At least when you use `biblatex` `location` is a list field, so the correct *input on the `.bib` side* would be `location = {Amsterdam and New York and London},` and the output can be easily customised. I would probably go for a simple comma-separated list in the output, I feel that dashes would look just wrong and weirdly en-dashes attract my attention in a way that is probably not really useful for secondary information like the location of the publisher.

Comment: I'd consider hyphens as wrong, as they denote a connection and therefore imo should be reserved for merged place-names ("Alsace-Lorraine") or perhaps suburbs ("Stockholm-Södermalm"). Personally I like to use (breakable) `\slash`es for alternate publishing places "Amsterdam/New York/London".